# How to manually uninstall PGAdmin4 from macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, pgadmin, psql, pgadmin3

I have tried removing manually by removing PGAdmin4 from my applications folder. I also followed a few steps from this [post here](https://superuser.com/questions/720014/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-pgadmin3-from-os-x). To my surprise some of the files existed and I was able to remove them. However now when I run:

```
ps aux | grep postgres
```

Which results in:

```
1703   0.0  0.0 34252392    636 s000  R+    6:42PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox postgres
```

When I run `psql`, I still see the command being registered and fails with,

```
psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

For the next step I am trying the following command:

```
locate bin/psql
```

Which results in:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/psql
/Library/PostgreSQL/14/bin/psql
/Library/PostgreSQL/14/debug_symbols/bin/psql.dSYM
/Library/PostgreSQL/14/debug_symbols/bin/psql.dSYM/Contents
/Library/PostgreSQL/14/debug_symbols/bin/psql.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist
/Library/PostgreSQL/14/debug_symbols/bin/psql.dSYM/Contents/Resources
/Library/PostgreSQL/14/debug_symbols/bin/psql.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF
/Library/PostgreSQL/14/debug_symbols/bin/psql.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/psql
/Users/Shared/DBngin/postgresql/11.0/bin/psql
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@11/11.16/bin/psql
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.11_1/bin/psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

I deleted the above mentioned folders but I still see the same result for `locate`. At this point I am not sure what should be my next steps to take to remove PGAdmin4 successfully from my Mac. Any pointers how I can remove it completely?

I'm planning to install PostgreSQL through Homebrew next but for that to work this copy needs to go.

Comment: “I deleted the above mentioned folders but I still see the same result for `locate`.” All that means is the `locate` database has not updated yet; `locate` caches data. You could wait a day or so and check again or you can run this command: `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`. Wait for it to complete and try `locate bin/psql` again.

Answer (score 0):

### It seems like you don’t have an uninstall problem but rather a “still running process” problem.

To resolve this, launch “Activity Monitor” (“Applications > Utilities > Activity Monitor”) search for `postgres`, select it and click the stop sign “X” in the upper left hand area of the title bar of “Activity Monitor.”

[image]

That should quit the `postgres` process and you should be good.

Similarly, open the “Terminal” (“Applications > Utilities > Terminal”) and try `sudo kill -HUP 1703` (or whatever process ID it has when you run `ps aux | grep postgres`) and that should kill it as well.

Or, could have cleanly uninstalled PGAdmin4 by using [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/):

- Install AppCleaner.
- Launch it and drag the PGAdmin4 application to AppCleaner.
- Let AppCleaner do its magic a little bit.
- When ready you will be presented with a list of files that will be deleted.
- Looks good? Go ahead and delete the files and that’s that.
- Et voilà! All cleaned up.

In fact, I would say you should reinstall PGAdmin4 via the application and once that is done, then do what I just described with the AppCleaner process to be 100% sure it is uninstalled.